# PHP & MySQL saving data from MySQL into SESSIONS in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bit of a problem, sure one of you experts can assist :-p.

I have the following tables in the database:

b_admins:

```
id
username
password
email
locationid
```

b_locations

```
id
name
description
```

Login Script:

```
<?php

    // Inialize session
    session_start();

    // Connection to MySQL Database.
    include ('_includes/_dbconnection.php');
    include ('_includes/_dbopen.php');

    // Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input
    $login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM b_admins WHERE (ausername = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "') and (apassword = '" .           mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) . "')");

    // Check username and password match
    if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {

    // Set username session variable
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];

    // Set locationid session varaible //// Modified 12 April 2012.
    $_SESSION['locationid'] = $row_Recordset1["locationid"];

    $locationid = $_SESSION['locationid'];

    // Jump to secured page
    header('Location: _home.php');
    }

    else {

    // Jump to login page
    header('Location: index.php');
    }

    // Script Source: http://frozenade.wordpress.com/2007/11/24/how-to-create-login-page-in-php-and-mysql-with-session/

?>
```

My homepage script:

```
    // Check, if user is already login, if login proceed to _home.php
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('Location: _home.php');
    }


    // Load Header file.
    include ('_includes/_header.php');

    // Template Construction.

    // Create Homepage Layout after $home01.
    $home01 = '<div id="imglogo"></div>
                <div id="container">
                <div class="top"> 
                <div id="logo">
                </div>
                <ul class="socialicons">
                </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="content" >
                <div id="home"> 
                <div class="latest">';


    // MySQL Load Location Name from MySQL database after $home02.
    $home02 = '<h3>';


    // Create Notification Area for the Administrator after $home03.
    $home03 = '&nbsp; Administrator Panel</h3><p>You are logged in to make changes to your Branch, only your Branch details can be changed  within this Administration Panel. You may proceed to make any changes using the menu at the bottom.</p></div>
                <!-- /Latest section -->

                <!-- News info section -->
                <ul class="news-info">
                <li><label>Users Registered</label>';


    //MySQL Load User count from MySQL database after $home04.
    $home04 = '<span>';


    // Close Template.
    $home05 = '</span></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- /News info section -->
                </div>        
                <!-- /Home --> 

                <!-- Menu -->
                <div class="menu">
                <ul class="tabs">
                <li><a href="_home.php" class="tab-home"></a></li>
                <li><a href="_events.php" class="tab-events"></a></li>
                <li><a href="_gallery.php" class="tab-portfolio"></a></li>
                <li><a href="_template_edit.php" class="tab-contact"></a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                </div>';

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Combining Template with MySQL Data.

    /// Build Home Page from MySQL database.

     $SQL = "SELECT * FROM b_admins, b_locations WHERE locationid ='$locationid'  LIMIT 0, 1";
            $result = mysql_query($SQL);

            while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                echo $home01;
                echo $home02;
                print $db_field['lcity'];
                echo $home03;
            }

    /// Build Home Page News Section from MySQL database.
                echo $home04;
    $SQL = "SELECT count( * ) as total_record  FROM `b_users` WHERE locationid = '$locationid'";
                echo $home05;

    /// Load Footer and Database close file.
    include ('_includes/_footer.php');
    include ('_includes/_dbclose.php');

?>
```

I would like to save the value 'locationsid' from b_admins to be able to use the SQL to retrieve data from the database where the 'locationsid' is the same as from the table in the database b_locations.

I also receive the following error that i have no clue on how to fix when logged in though the login script:
"The webpage at http://localhost/xxxxx/_home.php has resulted in too many redirects."

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Where did you get this code from? :)

Comment: Got the login from:http://frozenade.wordpress.com/2007/11/24/how-to-create-login-page-in-php-and-mysql-with-session/

Answer (score 1):

seems like you need to fetch the record first
you will need to fetch the Mysql result to get the record

```
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_array($login, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$_SESSION['locationid'] = $row_Recordset1["locationid"];
```

also the homepage also needs a session_start(); or it will never be valid as no session exists on load of page only after function call

if you still end up with header redirects you could use html meta refresh
also watch you don't point redirects to same page

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

When you say "homepage script" is this file index.php or _home.php?

If it is _home.php, you do not need the following lines:

```
// Check, if user is already login, if login proceed to _home.php
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header('Location: _home.php');
}
```

This could be what is causing the redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

i think your query is also wrong.

```
// Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input
$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM b_admins WHERE (ausername = '" .mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "') and (apassword = '" .          mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) . "')");
```

There's a typo in your code.

**ausername** should be **`username`**
**apassword** should be **`passsword`**

Comment: That was fixed and still no go, i`m trying to get a way to store data from the user that logins (his locationid) so that i can use that in the _home.php to retrieve data from the mysql database in other tables that is associated with the locationid.

Comment: first of all you need to start session on your homepage script..........and My friend u are already storing the locationId of the user who is logged in. Just access the $_SESSION['locationId'].

Comment: I still not able, event if i try to print or echo to see if i get any value

Comment: start session is there, think the problem is with the login script not providing the data.